# Play Install Referrer Library not returning complete URL

Tags: android, google-play, install-referrer

**Background**

I'm using [Google Play Install Referrer Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library) in my native Android app to track some UTM parameters. To test my implementation, I use [Google Play URL Builder](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder) to generate test URLs for my app (which is on Internal Testing by the way).

**Problem**

On the `ReferrerDetails` object, getting `installReferrer` returns an incomplete URL i.e. a URL with only the query parameters and nothing else e.g. `utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=myUtmTerm&utm_content=myUtmContent&utm_campaign=myCampaignName&anid=admob`. I cannot really call `Uri.parse()` to convert this into a URI and get the query parameters directly (the query parameters are null if I try to do that since it's not a valid URI). My other option is to use a custom parser built just for this that I'm trying to avoid for my convenience. Is there another way around it?

Here is the code block that I am using to get this UTM data.

```
//other code
...
referrerClient = InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder(context).build()
referrerClient.startConnection(object : InstallReferrerStateListener {
    override fun onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(responseCode: Int) {
        when (responseCode) {
            InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.OK -> {
                val response: ReferrerDetails = referrerClient.installReferrer
                val referrerUrl: String = response.installReferrer
                referrerClient.endConnection()
            }
            ...
        }
    }
```